# Some questions about $f(z) = \frac 1 {e^z -1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z):= \frac 1 {e^z-1}$.
First question: Why has $f$ a pole of order $1$ in $z = 0$? Second question: How can we determine the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n} a_n z^n$ which is the Laurent-series of $f$ around $z=0$ ? I have computed that
$$
 \forall n >  0: b_n = - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{b_i}{(n+1-i)!}
$$ where $a_n = b_{n+1}$ and $a_{-1} = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: What would the radius of convergence of $g(z)=\dfrac{z}{e^z-1}$ be around $z=0$?

Second hint: When is $e^z-1=0$?

Comment: I guess $g$ has $\infty$ as radius of convergence since $$ g(z) = 1 / \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {z^n}{(n+1)!}$$ ?

Comment: I don't understand that comment, @Andre. The radius of convergence of a series is the radius at which the nearest pole of the function occurs. What are the poles of $g(z)$?

Comment: $e^z = 1 \iff z = 2\pi ik$ for $k \in \mathbb Z$ so $2\pi$ would be the nearest pole (except 0). I.e. the series converges on $\{z \in \mathbb C \mid 0 < |z| < 2 \pi \}$ ?

Comment: Well, the nearest poles would be $\pm 2\pi i$, but yes, you've got the correct radius.

Comment: Yep. That was in my mind :D

Answer (score 0):

Poles depend on denominator. $e^z = 1+ z + z^2/2 + z^3/3 +\cdots$ Therefore $e^z -1= z + z^2/2 + z^3/3 +\cdots=(z-0)(1 - z/2 + z^2/3 +\cdots)$. since $z-0$ has power $1$ therefore it is a pole of order $1$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability to format questions using MathJax (see FAQ). Regards